# Error: case object and rules don't agree [overload conflict]

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am working on a function that finds the largest number in a list.

```
fun maxValue(xs) =
  case xs of
      [] => []
    | first::rest => if ((first)>hd(rest))
                     then maxValue(first :: tl(tl(rest)))
                     else maxValue(rest)
val list = [1,2,4,8,3]
val ans = maxValue list
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
= stdIn:2.5-6.40 Error: case object and rules don't agree [overload conflict]
rule domain: [> ty] list list
object: [> ty] list
in expression:
(case xs
  of :: (x,nil) => x
   | :: (xs,rest) =>
       if hd <exp> > hd <exp>
       then maxValue (<exp> :: <exp>)
       else maxValue (tl <exp>))
```

I am not understanding what the error means, why the code doesn't compile. Is there something I am missing and how do I fix this?

**Edit:** Changed certain variable names from xs to first for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a couple of questions about your function:

1. Where are you returning the max value?
2. Why are you trying to get the head of `first`? In your example `first` doesn't has a head because it is `1`, i. e. the head of the list you are passing as argument
3. Why are you trying to get the tail of the tail of `rest`?

To solve this class of problems with recursion I use a helper function that holds the recursive structure as first argument and the possible result as the second argument. This is my attempt:

```
fun maxValue xs =
  let
    fun helper xs chosen =
      case xs of
          [] => chosen
        | first :: [] =>
            if first > chosen
            then first
            else chosen
        | first :: rest =>
            if first > hd rest
            then helper rest first
            else helper rest (hd rest)
  in
    helper xs 0
  end
```

In the case of a null list I'm simply returning 0 to avoid complicating.

Lately I'm using [Poly/ML](http://polyml.org) instead of SML/NJ. The errors seems more friendly

Comment: 1) that does seem to be missing
2) Good catch with the head of first of list.
3) reason why i wanted tail of the tail was that so if the head of he rest was less it would skip over that value when re-appending first to the list

But your answer works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: `maxValue [~1]` should not give 0. I don't think `maxValue []` should, either.

Comment: Yup, I know. I mentioned that, I wanted to answer with the minimum amount of code. I am not claiming it is the perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

My professor was kind enough to provide me with the following alternate solution and explanation:

There are several issues with your recursive case: you’re taking the head of the first element of the list, and comparing it to the second element of the list in your if statement. Then you’re applying your function to the head of the first element of the list cated together with the first element of the list with its first element removed?

Here’s how I’d suggest implementing this function instead:

```
fun maxValue(xs) =
    case xs of
     x::[] => x
    | first::rest =>
          let
              val maxRest = maxValue(rest)
          in
              if first > maxRest
              then first
              else maxRest
          end
```

Comment: This version is similarly not explicit about how it will explode and thus warns about pattern matching not being exhaustive. Ignoring your compiler's warnings is dangerous; it should give you the thought that you're not done yet. If you want to write impartial functions, you should at least raise a meaningful exception when it fails, e.g. `raise Empty`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is unsafe because it assumes that `hd rest`, `tl rest` and `tl (tl rest)` have meaningful values, but when `rest` is empty, these cause a `raise Empty`. Here are two safe variants: 1) `maximum1` assumes the existence of at least one element, but doesn't presume what it is. 2) `maximumOpt` returns `NONE` when the list is empty:

```
fun maximum1 x xs = foldl Int.max x xs
fun maximumOpt [] = NONE
  | maximumOpt (x::xs) = SOME (maximum1 x xs)
```

In the first case the problem rests with giving input to the function; in the second case with handling its output. Depending on where you have the best opportunity to handle errors in your program, one or the other might be better.

**Edit:** In light of the other answers providing unsafe solutions with various shortcomings (unjustified default values, pattern matching not exhaustive) here is a short variant that throws a meaningful exception:

```
fun maximum [] = raise Empty
  | maximum (x::xs) = foldl Int.max x xs
```

And one that uses explicit recursion rather than folding:

```
fun maximum [] = raise Empty
  | maximum [x] = x
  | maximum (x::y::xs) = maximum (Int.max(x, y)::xs)
```

Comment: Yes your code is superior in terms of application. I was studying for a midterm that was testing the applications of recursion, case statements and such. So for the reasons of practice is what led me to that solution.